# Как извлечь информацию из файла?

Tags: email, php

```
<?php

mail ("<?php include "e-mail.txt" ?>", "тест", "тест", "тест")

?>
```

Пишет ошибку в третьей строке. Как я понимаю, нельзя делать вот так, код:

```
..."<?php include "e-mail.txt" ?>"...
```

Ну, а как тогда извлечь инфу из файла в подобных случаях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$content = file_get_contents("e-mail.txt");
```

И замените тире на подчёркивание, - на _ , может компилятор воспринять это за знак минуса.

Comment: Знак минуса в имени файла воспримет. С file_get_contents() согласен. + в карму.

Comment: `$content = file_get_contents("e-mail.txt"); mail ($content, "тест", "тест", "тест");`  
Cделать так ^

Comment: kemerov4anin, так правильней ;)
`$content = file_get_contents("e-mail.txt"); mail ("$content", "тест", "тест", "тест");`

Comment: А если ещё добавить, то используйте одиночные кавычки, чтобы тире не казалось минусом, вот так : file_get_contents('e-mail.txt'); ибо в двойных могут происходить операции).

Comment: @nick777, @Андрей, боже мой, что за чушь вы несете?

Comment: Не факт, далеко не факт, стал бы я твердить об этом, убедившись в обратном.

Comment: Я привел вам ссылку на описание строковых констант, а вот ваше утверждение голословно. Либо приведите пруфлинки, либо соответсвующий код.

Comment: Никому, ничего доказывать не собираюсь.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fh = fopen("e-mail.txt", "r");
$data = fread($fh, filesize("e-mail.txt"));
fclose($fn);
mail ($data, "тест", "тест", "тест");
```